# Builder design patterns: passing parameters from client to the builder

Tags: design-patterns

Does the builder design pattern allow passing parameters?
If yes, what is right way to achieve it?

### Overview

The builder pattern is about hiding the details of object constructon, it places two layers of abstraction between the product and the client: builder and director

- builder is the interface for product construction, the idea is
  polymorphism: same methods are used to set different products
- director separates client from the building process
- Builder pattern is meant for complex products, so the builder interface could be large: `setPart1()`, `setPart2()`, ... `setPart100()`
- director has small and simple interface: `constructProduct()`, `getProduct()`
- same director could use different concrete builders for different concrete products
- but also same builder interface could be used by different directors

What if some properties of the product cannot be hidden from the client.

### Example problem

Assume we have the complex product such as computer set.

```
class ComputerSet {
private:
    string procName;
    string hddName;
    int hddCapacity;
public:
    ComputerSet(string p) : procName(p) {}
    void setHdd(string name, int capacity);
};

void ComputerSet::setHdd(string name, int capacity) {
  hddName = name;
  hddCapacity = capacity;
}
```

Actually, it is not so complex. The product has only 3 parts to set: `procName`, `hddName`, `hddCapacity`. The reason is to make example small. Let's say the computer set could have many components.

Dividing *HDD* part into two parts (*name* and *capacity*) has been done for the simplicity of the example. They have different nature: `hddName` is *builder-constant*, `hddCapacity` is *builder-variant*.

Let's assume there is the concrete product: computer set with `procName="Amdel"` and `hddName="Orange"`. These details could be hidden from the client. The client:

- creates the instance of the Director
- creates the instance of the AmdelBuilder
- passes AmbelBuilder to the Director
- uses Director's inteface to get the product
- does not know about "Amdel" and "Orange" strings

But there could be many HDD capacities to choose: 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000.

One way is to create the builder for each capacity: AmdelBuilder250, AmdelBuilder500, AmdelBuilder750, AmdelBuilder1000, AmdelBuilder1500, AmdelBuilder2000.

What about designing only one `AmbelBuilder` for each capacities and passing `hddCapacity` parameter just before the product is created?
How to pass the parameter:

- contain it **inside the builder** as its property (data member);
  two kinds of settings both **from the client level**

  - set with constructor (once per instance)
  - set with the setter (setting multiple values per single instance)
- make it **the argument of the builder method**, it has to be passed **from the director level**

  - make it the argument of the director construction method
  - contain it inside the director as its property (data member)

### First Approach

The Builder stores the `hddCapacity` as own data field

```
class Builder {
protected:
    ComputerSet *cs;
    int hddCapacity;
public:
    Builder(int capacity = 250) : hddCapacity(capacity) {  }
    virtual void createComputerSet() = 0;
    virtual void setHdd() = 0;
    ComputerSet* returnComputerSet() { return cs; }
};
```

Concrete builder's `setHdd()` method does not need parameters

```
class AmdelBuilder : public Builder {
public:
    void createComputerSet();
    void setHdd();
    AmdelBuilder(int capacity = 500) : Builder(capacity) { }
};

void AmdelBuilder::createComputerSet() {
    cs = new ComputerSet("Amdel");
}
void AmdelBuilder::setHdd() {
    cs->setHdd("Orange", hddCapacity);
}
```

The director does not know about the `hddCapacity` parameter

```
class Director {
private:
    Builder *builder;
public:
    void setBuilder(Builder *b) { builder = b; }
    void constructComputerSet();
    ComputerSet* getComputerSet() { return builder->returnComputerSet(); }
};

void Director::constructComputerSet() {
    builder->createComputerSet();
    builder->setHdd();
}
```

because the client sets `AmdelBuilder.hddCapacity` when the client creates the `Builder` instance

```
Director* d = new Director();
Builder* ba = new AmdelBuilder(750); // Amdel + Orange HDD 750
d->setBuilder(ba);
d->constructComputerSet();
ComputerSet* csa750 = d->getComputerSet();
```

### Other solution

Builder does not store `hddCapacity`, but the `setHdd()` method requires `hddCapacity` parameter.

```
class Builder {
protected:
    ComputerSet *cs;
public:
    Builder() {  }
    virtual void createComputerSet() = 0;
    virtual void setHdd(int hddCapacity) = 0;
    ComputerSet* returnComputerSet() { return cs; }
};
```

The director is the direct user of the Builder's API. So the director must know the `hddCapacity` value.

### Question

What should is the best practice that does not violate the OO principles and the encapsulation idea of the builder pattern?

Comment: Aside from not understanding why you need to use this pattern, I don't understand why you cannot use parameters in the constructor. How exactly is this pattern making your code smaller and simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe neither of your approaches violate anything and both can be used just fine.

Passing parameters to the builder can be done either using constructor or setter methods. I do not see any problem with it.

I tend to pass parameters via constructor if there are not so many of them. If I have more than 3-5 configuration parameters I switch to using methods to configure Builder.